# Is the Hall coefficient a resistance?

Tags: electrical-resistance, quantum-hall-effect

The [Hall coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect) is defined as this:

$$R_H=\frac{E_y}{j_xB_z}.$$

Always as $R_H$. I am currious as to how to use this coefficient? Is it the y-direction resistance/resistivity (it is very close to the general resistivity from Ohm's law $\rho = E/j$)? Then I should be able to find it by $R_H=V_y/I_y$ (or $R_H=E_y/j_y$).

or is it simply defined as this as a proportionality constant (it does indeed look good with the three factors combined around one constant) and not an actual physical quantity?

Comment: It is related to Hall conductance (i.e. $I_x/E_y$) and obviously a physical quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a resistance. Remember we are interested in the electric field developed in the y direction as a result of current flowing in the x-direction. Applying Lorentz law and electron sea model in metals, we expect it to be proportional to the current in x-direction and magnetic field. Therefore, an introduction of a constant which will depend on the material properties.

Answer (score 1):

when the field in the y direction starts to be build in the sample (it means when we apply the magnetic field), we see a voltage drop between the two ends in the x direction. but after the equilibrium of the deflection current (due to the magnetic field) and its apposing electric field (due to the charge accumulation) in the y direction, the current in the x direction goes as it was before applying the magnetic field. and what you measure is that field constructed along the so called y direction.